# k-compact vectored I/O

Tags: reference-request, computer-networks, memory-hardware

I have a practical programming problem that I am struggling to find an optimal algorithm for, in part because I don't know what to call it. The problem concerns [vectored I/O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectored_I%2FO) (scatter/gather).

Consider a server *s* and a set of connected clients *C*. The server maintains a contiguous array *B* of variable-length blocks of data in its memory. For each block in *B*, there is some subset of *C* that are "subscribed" to the block. At fixed intervals, the server sends each client all of its subscribed blocks.

I would like to use vectored I/O to optimize the sending by constructing a static I/O vector (array of pointer/length pairs) describing the location of each client's subscribed blocks at the server. This can be done trivially as so:

```
for (block in B) {
    for (client in block.subscribers) {
        client.io_vec.append(block.addr, block.len);
    }
}
```

However, the network hardware I am using has a limit on the number of I/O vectors which can make up one message, which I will call *k*. So, I need to figure out how to lay out *B* such that I can construct vectors of length <= *k*, where *k* is much smaller than |*B*|. *B* can be rearranged freely, and blocks can be sent to the client in a different order than their order in server memory.

I am already confident that it is impossible to do this with no copying of blocks at the server for arbitrary *B* and *k*. Rather, my plan is to start from a conservative solution of entirely separate regions for each client, where each region contains a copy of all subscribed blocks (and can be described by an I/O vector of length 1), and then merge those regions as much as possible, with the constraint that all client I/O vectors must have a length <= *k*.

However, I'd like to check whether I'm reinventing the wheel before I spend a lot of time on this. Does what I'm describing match a known problem/algorithm? It feels like it might, but I just don't know the magic words to search for.